# Git hooks in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, hook

I would like to implement client-side git hook (type of commit-msg) to validate commit message. I have done a working hook - it works perfectly when using git console. 
But Visual Studio 2015 git build-in plugin (Team Explorer) seems not to take it into account and simply skip those hooks.

Has anyone tried to do the same with success? I read the Internet and it seems the problem is not solved, but I believie in You! :)

I want to check if commit message contain jira issue key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of writing, not possible.

There is a feature request for that, and you can upvote it if it's important to you: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4321705-enable-client-side-hooks-when-committing-code-to-a

Comment: Update: as of Visual Studio 2017 client-side Git hooks are run.

Answer (score 2):

Git hooks work with VS2017 and upwards. The only caveat is there is no proper way to manage the hook scripts with your source code since it lives in a folder that is not version controlled. I've been using a pre-build event as a workaround to copy the hooks into .git folder so I get to keep the hooks scripts within my sources.

Comment: The hooks can be managed in the source code by setting the git config core.hookspath to a path which is present in the repo.